# EXCEPTION: UnCaught (in Promise). Injectioned Service in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I can´t render an angular´s component, and I can´t figure it out.

It is something related with the method which is calling a services for injecting data. It is returning the error´s message below:

**EXCEPTION: UnCaught (in Promise)**

This is my relevant code:

**cartelera-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CarteleraService } from './cartelera.service';
import { Pelicula } from './pelicula.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'cartelera-list',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let pelicula of cartelera"> 
        <p>+++ {{ pelicula.titulo }} - {{ pelicula.genero }} - {{ pelicula.duracion }} </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
  providers: [CarteleraService]
})

    export class CarteleraListComponent implements OnInit {

    public cartelera: Pelicula[];

    contructor(private carteleraService: CarteleraService) {}

    getPeliculas(): void {
        this.carteleraService.getPeliculas().then((cartelera: Pelicula[]) => this.cartelera = cartelera);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getPeliculas();
    }

}
```

**cartelera.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Pelicula } from './pelicula.model';
import { CARTELERA } from './pelicula-data';

@Injectable()
export class CarteleraService {
    getPeliculas(): Promise<Pelicula[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(CARTELERA);
    }
}
```

The param CARTELERA, returned by the service, is just a const compound by a list of Pelicula (interface - model).

**Note**: The complet message´s error is :

***EXCEPTION: UnCaught (in Promise)
Cannot read property 'getPeliculas' of undefined error.***

***Note***: I tried this sentence before

**contructor(private carteleraService: CarteleraService) {}**

But, when I used it, the next error appear, in compile time.

[image: Error]

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

import { routing } from './app.routing';

import { SociosComponent } from './socios.component';
import { Index } from './index';
import { CarteleraComponent } from './cartelera.component';
import { CarteleraListComponent } from './cartelera-list.component';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing    
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent,
    SociosComponent,
    Index,
    CarteleraComponent,
    CarteleraListComponent
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Please, check mi aditional Note. @echonax

Comment: Please, check mi aditional Note. @AJT_82

Comment: For the heck of it, "provide" the service from the module that this component belongs to (so "app" or whatever else if you're using a feature module). Otherwise do everything the same (with the correct constructor config). See what happens. As far as an application architecture/pattern, I tend to think in terms of modules providing and components consuming, and the examples and so on available seem to bear that out. I'm not sure I ever tried to "provide" a service from a component, and I'm not even sure if a component can (or should) "provide" a service to itself.

Comment: Oh and BTW Angular 2 says "error in promise" sorts of things for almost everything, and loads up your console with scary red vomit that often makes it difficult to find out the problem was something as simple as a typo in an element name or something.

Comment: My english is not good enough, but If I understand you... so rude man... :S

Comment: Sorry for my manners... My english is not good enough... If you all want, please check my edited post. If you need something more, please, let me know. Thanks so much for waste your time in helping me. Thanks  :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean at all. I assure you my comments aren't rude. I am absolutely trying to help you. Provide the service from the module that this component belongs to, it could very well fix your problem unless something else is wrong, in which case you'll probably get a better error to help you figure it out.

Comment: Hi @TimConsolazio :) :). The service is defined in cartelera.sevice I posted it and the component which is using it is cartelera-list.component, I posted it as well. I did a few working demos with this approach and they work. Maybe the definition of my module (NgModule) in app is unright. But it is quite simple, btw I will post it, hoping you can help me with it. Cheers mate. :)

Comment: Hi @TimConsolazio. Just added the file you think could be interesting. If you need anything else, pls let me know. Thanks again, for your efford...

Comment: @GileadKenzo I updated my answer. I just notify you here, as I had alreay posted an answer and deleted it, so you will not be notified that I undeleted my answer. Your code should work now, based on my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echonax was almost correct. Besides the changes echonax suggested you have a typo:

```
contructor(private carteleraService: CarteleraService) {}
```

should be `constructor`, so you were missing `s`.

As a sidenote, I would remove the `providers: [CarteleraService]` from your cartelera-list.component, and declare it in your NgModule as providers:

```
providers: [CarteleraService]
```

that makes the service available in the whole module, so you do not need to import and declare it in all components that you need. Just a suggestion! ;)

Comment: Well, What Can I say? You again @AJT_82!!?? LOL, thanks man... :) :) :). Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
private carteleraService: CarteleraService;

contructor(carteleraService) {}
```

with

```
contructor(private carteleraService: CarteleraService) {}
```

This way Angular DI will inject `CarteleraService` to your `this.carteleraService`

Comment: Please, check mi aditional Note.

Comment: @EliasMP Did you remove `private carteleraService: CarteleraService;` from your fields? It should only exist in constructor.

Comment: I did it... Check it out. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for my manners... My english is not good enough... If you want, please check my edited post. If you need something more, please, let me know. Thanks so much for waste your time in helping me. Thanks @echonax :)

Comment: @EliasMP no problem at all sir, I'm trying to figure out what is wrong but couldn't find anything :(

Comment: Thanks :) I will post a solution if I find it on weekend :). Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

try using following way to manually write a `promise`

```
@Injectable()
export class CarteleraService {
    getPeliculas(): Promise<Pelicula[]> {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(CARTELERA);
  });
 }
}
```

you are not defining promise in right way. try console logging `getPeliculas` method in service it self to verify

Comment: Thanks. I didnt try this approach. I will do on weekend and let you all know. Cheers mate :) :). But I´m having problem trying to define the service property in the standard way, as @echonax said as well. My solution was to define the service in a private property out of the contructor. I am wondering, if it is right...

Comment: you have mentioned service in `providers` array + importing it rightly. Initializing in constructor is also correct. Just try `contructor(private carteleraService: CarteleraService) { console.log(this.carteleraService); }` to check what service is returning.

Comment: Yep, even I did a few working demos using this way, but I´m loosing something now. And I dont know what. I can´t reach the console.log either. When I launch tsc -p front, I am getting the error...

Comment: Hi @candidJ. Just tried your code, but I can´t still compile the files. tsc -p front, returns the error posted in my post... :S. Thanks man.